# Domain Redirects - Not all working - HTTPS time out / not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, web, dns

Ok the following are the urls for my site, ones marked with a tick work fine but the ones marked with an x either time out, or give an error like "This site can’t be reached domain.tld’s server IP address could not be found." in chrome.

I want all to redirect to https://taibhsedesigns.ie

```
(✓)   https://www.taibhsedesigns.ie
(✓)   http://www.taibhsedesigns.ie    
(✓)   https://taibhsedesigns.ie
(x)   http://taibhsedesigns.ie      
(✓)   www.taibhsedesigns.ie          
(x)   taibhsedesigns.ie


(x)   https://www.taibhsedesigns.com
(✓)   http://www.taibhsedesigns.com       
(x)   https://taibhsedesigns.com
(✓)   http://taibhsedesigns.com               
(✓)   www.taibhsedesigns.com                
(✓)   taibhsedesigns.com
```

So for details, my site is setup with blacknight Ireland, there is an ssl cert for the .ie domain, I don't have one for the .com domain so how can I fix timeouts for the https attempts at the .com domains or make them go to the http version and have it then redirect to the .ie?

Site is hosted on the .ie url with the .com setup to forward using standard forwarding in the control panel with black night.

My htaccess file for the .ie domain is as follows and the site is built using codeigniter,

```
RewriteEngine on

#remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

#force https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


#all below is custom and not orig to codeigniter


#redirects for broken links from old website
Redirect /index.html https://taibhsedesigns.ie/
Redirect /faq.html https://taibhsedesigns.ie/faq
Redirect /privacy.html https://taibhsedesigns.ie/privacy
Redirect /portfolio.php https://taibhsedesigns.ie/portfolio

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filters / compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/js
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon 

# Exception: Images
SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Drop problematic browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_filter.c>
  # Legacy versions of Apache
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

#protection from mime sniffing and security exploit
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

#Block access to the entire page when an XSS attack is suspected
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

#prevent click jacking and disallow pages being embedded in iframes on other sites
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature for security
 ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: When I test, `http://taibhsedesigns.ie` correctly rediredts to `https://taibhsedesigns.ie/`

Comment: And for `.com` https, there is nothing you can do without .com certificate, it is required even if redirect is all you want to do.

Comment: @DusanBajic I feared than, shall have to do without for now, seems the 2 .ie urls that dont work are only doing that in my chrome instance which is weird,